# Does WebSphere SSL Implementation Depend on OpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, openssl, websphere, websphere-8

I am facing some vulnerabilities in one WebSphere server 8.0 (see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21687173). The mitigation is to enable TLSv1.2.

However the OpenSSL version of the server is 0.9 and I know that this version does not support this version of TLS. So I wonder if the SSL implementation in WebSphere depends on the OpenSSL version. Unfortunately, I can't update OpenSSL (It is not the case to explain the why now :s).

If the websphere supports TLSv1.2. Is it possible to enable this protocol, even thought OpenSSL does not support it?

Comment: It almost certainly uses the IBM implementation of JSSE rather than OpenSSL.

Comment: I Know that in Tomcat you can choose which one you want, but I am not sure for Websphere and I am not finding the answer for sure

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IBM WebSphere and its SSL implementation is not using OpenSSL.

Check this post for more details: [The IBM Java JSSE does not use OpenSSL](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21669774)

Answer (score 3):

Answering the second part of the question: Enabling TLSv1.2 on WebSphere.

From version 8.0.0.3 of WebSphere Application Server, you can define the SSL Handshake protocol when defining an SSL configuration on the server. The supported protocols are SSLv2, SSLv3, TLS/TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2.

See [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_sslconfiguration.html) for the IBM Documentation on creating an SSL Configuration. Refer to step 14 for an explanation of all the listed handshake protocols.

To edit an existing SSL Configuration, navigate to Security > SSL certificate and key management > SSL configurations > [CONFIG_NAME] > Quality of protection (QoP) settings. On this page, you can specify TLSv1.2 as your handshake protocol.